# Teradata Character Compare

Tags: c#, sql, teradata

In a C# application, I have a DataTable being populated from a Teradata table.
The teradata table data looks like this:

```
UnitNum UnitName
------- --------
123456  Location A1 - 123456 
123456  Location B1 - 123456
```

I'd like to create output that looks like this:

```
UnitNum UnitName
------- --------
123456  Location A1 / B1 - 123456
```

I have accomplished this in C# with the following code:

```
string compSql2 = "SELECT UnitNum , 
                   UPPER(MAX((CASE a.RNK WHEN 1 THEN a.UnitName ELSE NULL END))) Location1,
                   UPPER(MAX((CASE a.RNK WHEN 2 THEN a.UnitName ELSE NULL END))) Location2 
                   FROM (SELECT UnitNum , UnitName, RANK(UnitName) AS RNK 
                     FROM idw_app_field_sync.compressor_list GROUP BY UnitNum) AS a 
                   GROUP BY 1";
        DataTable compdt = TeradataConnector.RunQuery(compSql2);

        compdt.Columns.Add("UnitName");
        for (int i = 0; i < compdt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (compdt.Rows[i].Field<string>("Location2") != null)
            {
                string loc1 = compdt.Rows[i].Field<string>("Location1");
                string loc2 = compdt.Rows[i].Field<string>("Location2");
                string unitname;

                for (int j = 0; j < loc1.Length - 9; j++)
                {
                    if (!loc2[j].Equals(loc1[j]))
                    {
                        unitname = loc2.Substring(0, loc2.Length - 9) + @" / " + loc1.Substring(j);
                        compdt.Rows[i].SetField<string>("UnitName", unitname);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                compdt.Rows[i].SetField<string>("UnitName", compdt.Rows[i].Field<string>("Location1"));
            }
        }
```

I'd like to accomplish this in Teradata SQL if at all possible. However, I do not know how to compare characters of strings with SQL like I did with C#.

Comment: Based on the SELECT there seem to be only two rows for each UnitNum and the last nine chars are always the same. Are there any other rules? Is the location name always one word or are there spaces?

Comment: The location names can have spaces. and for the two that share a UnitNum, the first part of the location name will be the same as well.

Comment: I forgot to ask: What's your Teradata release?

Comment: Teradata version 14.1